# Kill a subprocess after a time interval with Python in OS X

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I wrote a python script to initiate a subprocess and then want to kill this after an interval of n seconds . When I use time.sleep(n) it doesn't kills the process but when I remove this sleep part then it kills by using os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGKILL) . Can somebody please help me in this ?

```
    import time,subprocess,os,signal

    timeLeft = 5

    while timeLeft > 0:
       print('Time left is ' + str(timeLeft))
       time.sleep(1)
       timeLeft = timeLeft - 1
       pass

    proc = subprocess.Popen(['open','/Users/06 Green Day - Boulevard Of Broken Dreams.mp3'])

    time.sleep(2)

    os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

I tried with proc.terminate() too but in vain .

Answer (score 1):

Just kill it with `sys.exit(0).`

Comment: it didn't worked for me .the external application continued running.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time,subprocess,os,signal

proc = subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe","data.out"])

timeLeft = 5

while timeLeft > 0:
   print('Time left is ' + str(timeLeft))
   time.sleep(1)
   timeLeft = timeLeft - 1
   pass

os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

If you rearrange you code like this, it should start the process, count down `timeleft` and then kill the process. I did have to use `SIGTERM` though.

Comment: First, it didnt worked when I tried this with an mp3 file to open . The mp3 file was opened default by the iTunes app and it was not terminated , the mp3 continued playing .
Second , i was trying to make an alarm which starts after a given time and ends after a fixed time , so the position of starting the subprocess is not be changed.

Comment: @Prashant then manually choose the file to open it with like in my example, choose a program that correctly shuts down.